# looping technique with the data using variable name?

Tags: matlab, loops, signals, nested

This is my code program which is x is my data, and i have another data name such as af4,f7 and f8.. How can I do looping technique on my program, so that the x will be automatically change into af4, then f7 and last f8 in Matlab?

```
x=af3;
d = fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',4,5,1,40,128);
Hd = design(d,'butter');
fvtool(Hd);
y_delta = filter(Hd,x);
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you generate these variables `af4`, `af7` and `af8`? If you can create them as cells in a cell array or as fields in struct - your life would be much easier.

If you have no control over the variables, you can use `eval`:

```
varNames = {'af3', 'af4', 'af7', 'af8' }; % as strings
for vi=1:numel(varNames)
    x = eval( varNames{vi} ); % here''s the trick
    % continue here with x...
end
```

Note however that it is [extremely unrecomanded to use `eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you could use:

```
xCell = {af3, af4, af7, af8};

for xi = 1:nnumel(xCell)
     x = xCell{xi};
     % do what you want to do with x
end
```